# Very simple log4j2 properties configuration file using Console and Rolling File appender

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'd like a log4j2 properties file configuration with a console and a rolling file appender using log4j2 that can be used different application. The log configuration should rotate the log in production environment.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a standard log4j2 configuration as per industry standard. With some changes I can use that in the multiple application of my company.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think there is no such industry standard for logging or `log4j2` configuration. Everyone change the configuration as per the need of the application.

Below is one sample log4j2 configuration file having `ConsoleAppender` and `RollingFileAppender` -

```
status = warn
name= properties_configuration

# Give directory path where log files should get stored
property.basePath = ./log/

# ConsoleAppender will print logs on console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout

# Specify the pattern of the logs
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n


# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# Rotate log file each day and keep 30 days worth
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
# Delete files older than 30 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d

# Mention package name here in place of example. Classes in this package or subpackages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging         
logger.example.name = example
logger.example.level = debug
logger.example.additivity = false
logger.example.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
logger.example.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

# Configure root logger for logging error logs in classes which are in package other than above specified package
rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I need to add the host ip address to the log file. Is it possible without modifying the application java code code?

Comment: @SubhajitPal I think it is possible. Check this [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Property_Substitution). Another important point that it is entirely different question, so you should ask a new question.

Comment: one more question. I have used both timebased and sized base policies. The interval is 1 day for timebased policy. But if day changes from one to the next then the last log file of the previous date is not getting rolled over. It is not getting zipped with an incremental value.

Comment: I am getting this error `ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfLastModified  `

Comment: @Shoshi I hope you are including both lines -
 `appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified` and  
`appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d` .  If you are still facing, may be you can post your complete configuration and log4j2 version details in a separate question.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva I have got the problem. there was a trailing space after `IfLastModified` in my conf. thanks mate

Comment: @VikasSachdeva - great answer - after much log4j2/slf4j thrashing this was fixed things for me including controlling libraries using your "example" entries

Comment: @VikasSachdeva - I had a problem when I used this initially "ERROR Null object returned for Delete in DefaultRolloverStrategy" - the fix was to remove the trailing spaces from "IfLastModified" (as above).  I have taken the liberty of editting your answer for others

Comment: @Dazed thanks for the fix. Since `basePath` property already contains trailing `/` so I just modified `fileName` and `filePattern`. Hope it would work.

Comment: Hi all, as the OP asks for "very simple" configuration, I'm wondering why the answer includes these redundant parts: a) `rootLogger.additivity = false` - `rootLogger` doesn't have a parent, so this line is useless, b) `logger.example` sets `additivity = false` but it also uses the same appenders as the `rootLogger`, so the 3 lines can be deleted. Or have I missed something?

Comment: logs are not going in file and file is not getting created

Comment: @VikasSachdeva, I want to apply same rolling file appender to different log files that i maintain error.log, log.log ( i have multiple appenders) , will the below settings work ?
logger.fileLogger.appenderRefs = debugLoggerAppender,commonLoggerAppender, errorLoggerAppender
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.debugLoggerAppender.ref = LOGFILE
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.commonLoggerAppender.ref = RollingFile

Comment: @rinilnath i think it should work

Comment: @VikasSachdeva, can you also please show the size based rolling limit say 10MB? In the above example

Comment: @rinilnath Possibly, this answer can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398288/7152019 else you can post a new question for that.

Comment: After doing similar changes for structured streaming job on spark 3.3.1, I see only logs of driver code or application master in the app.log file. Console logs are coming fine. Any clue why this can happen? Also tried other config suggested by swapnil shashank and that too showing only driver or AM logs in the log file. Actual log statements added in the code do not show up.

Answer (score 5):

Try this out:

```
# Declare loggers
name=LoggingConfig
appenders=a_console, a_rolling
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=ar_console,ar_rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.ar_console.ref=StdoutAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.ar_rolling.ref=DailyRollingAppender
 
# Console logger
appender.a_console.type=Console
appender.a_console.name=StdoutAppender
appender.a_console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.a_console.layout.pattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) - %m%n
 
# File logger
appender.a_rolling.type=RollingFile
appender.a_rolling.name=DailyRollingAppender
appender.a_rolling.layout.pattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) - %m%n
 
appender.a_rolling.fileName=log4j2-sample.log
appender.a_rolling.filePattern=log4j2-sample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
 
appender.a_rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.a_rolling.policies.type=Policies
appender.a_rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.a_rolling.policies.time.interval=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest config if you just need to use console appender.

```
name=config
appenders=console
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
#appender.console.layout.pattern =%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %c{1} [%-5level] - %msg%n
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT

#if you want to make package specific configuration
#logger.org.apache=warn
```