# Log4j MaxFileSize with DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

My Goal is to **generate** log file on each day but of `MaxFileSize=100KB`

So I used DailyRollingFileAppender since I am using log4j 2.2 version

Date is working fine and when I used MaxFileSize it didnt worked and new file was not created based on filesize still date is working.

**Problem**: MaxFileSize not working with DatePattern for DailyRollingfileAppender

Here is log4j.properties file code:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/abc
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=80KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
```

Something need to be changed in date pattern but dont know yet

Comment: Is it working at all?

Comment: @RomanC yes but not on maxfilesize so you know I want this : filename.date.1, filename.date.2 for same date if file size is reached then next file is created with just simple formatted numbering

Comment: I don't think `log4j 2.2` version has `DailyRollingFileAppender `. It seems you are using log4j version 1 configuration

Comment: @VikasSachdeva thanks vikas I figured it out but now I have to redo it again since log4j 2.x is different from log4j 1.x. Can you please send the configuration for log4j 2 for the above corresponding configuration of log4j 1.x. Please post it as an answer

Comment: @VikasSachdeva task was to roll over date and size

Answer (score 1):

Try below configuration for rotating the file based on time and size -

```
status = warn
name= properties_configuration

property.basePath = ${catalina.home}/logs/

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %level %c{1}:%L - %msg%n
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName=${basePath}/abc.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=${basePath}abc_%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %level (%F:%L) - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 100 KB

# write your package name as the value of this key
logger.example.name = log4j2.example
logger.example.level = info
logger.example.additivity = false
logger.example.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
logger.example.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger
```

Comment: I exactly did the same thing but it isn't working though I know its right since the exact xml based configuration is working see my answer above for xml based configuration

Answer (score 0):

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE xml>
    <Configuration>
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            </Console>

            <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
            <RollingFile name="RollingFile">
                <FileName>C:/logs/x2c.log</FileName>
                <FilePattern>C:/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}-%i.log</FilePattern>
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>style{%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a}}{black} %-5p %style{[%t]}{blue} %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="2"
                        modulate="true" />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="80 KB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
            </RollingFile>

        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Logger name="com.mkyong.common.controller" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            </Logger>
            <Root level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>

    </Configuration>
```

This is the xml based configuration which is working fine but exact properties or basic configuration isn't working. File not created and no console output