# Log4j2.properties file writing logs into.log file but not into .err file

Tags: log4j2

I want to generate INFO AND ERROR log levels  into one file and ERROR level logs into another file using log4j2.properties file. log4j2.properties file only writing into only one of the file.
But when i use log4j2.xml file, it is working as expected.
I have been gone through so many blogs but didn't find solution.Please help
My .properties file :::

```
 //name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = file1,file2

appender.file1.type = File
appender.file1.name = LOGFILE
appender.file1.fileName=/myfolder/${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file1.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file1.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file2.type = File
appender.file2.name = ERRORFILE
appender.file2.fileName=/myfolder/${filename}/errorlog.err
appender.file2.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file2.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers = file1,file2
logger.file1.name=com.hello
logger.file1.level = INFO
logger.file1.appenderRefs = file
logger.file1.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
logger.file1.additivity = false

logger.file2.name=com.hello
logger.file2.level = ERROR
logger.file2.appenderRefs = file
logger.file2.appenderRef.file.ref = ERRORFILE
logger.file2.additivity = false

rootLogger.level = debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two loggers with the same name. You need to use one logger with two appender-refs with each Appender ref specifying the log levels.

```
logger.file1.name=com.hello
logger.file1.level=info
logger.file1.appenderRefs = file1,file2
logger.file1.appenderRef.file1.ref = LOGFILE
logger.file1.appenderRef.file1.level = INFO
logger.file1.appenderRef.file2.ref = ERRORFILE
logger.file1.appenderRef.file2.level = ERROR
logger.file1.additivity = false;
```

BTW - the same would hold true for a log4j2.xml.

Comment: Thanks rgoers for your help.The above configuration is working.Can you help adding the policies for the above log files ?

Comment: What policies? Triggering policies? You have not configured rolling file appenders.

Comment: Then you need to configure rolling file appenders, not file appenders. See the accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360848/very-simple-log4j2-properties-configuration-file-using-console-and-rolling-file

Comment: yes rgoers.I want to configure triggering policies(TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy and SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy).for the above log files.

Comment: does rollingfileappender can roll two log files(i.e in our case)?What I can see in the accepted link is configuration written for only one log file.Can you help to log two log files ?

Comment: Yes, just configure 2 appenders. Not for the same file of course.